# Send signals (text messages) to some server at regular intervals?

Tags: python, multithreading

My first post on SO (excited). I'm currently implementing a messaging system between me (the client) and some remote machine (the server). Now this server goes on maintenance during the weekend. I have a class for a messaging session with a `log_in` method and a `log_out` method.

```
class MessagingSession():
    def log_in():
        # some log in code
        # ...
    def log_out():
        # some log out code
        # ...
```

My question is how can I write some function/method which runs in the background, regularly checks time and when it's time to log out calls the `log_out` function and when it's time to log in calls the `log_in` function.

Comment: On SO it is expected that you have tried to solve the problem already and you should provide some real code.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `Thread` from the `threading` module with a while loop and sleeps in it to check the time every n seconds and, if it is (past) the desired time, then it can call your methods.

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def check_time(logout_time, sleep_milliseconds):
    while time.time() < logout_time:
        time.sleep(sleep_milliseconds)
    logout()

Thread(target=check_time, daemon=True, args=(logout_time, 1000)).start()
```

That's only some rough code, you'll have to fill in some of the blanks from your own code and put it in the appropriate spot, but you get the idea.

Comment: Well sir, you did bette than me :)

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use the time lib :

```
import time
currTime = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
setTime = "00:00:00"
if currTime == setTime:
    #logout
```

If you want to run it side by side with your main program, look for multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use threading which is a python module. You can try to create a thread which loop check every X seconds if your condition has satisfied.

Here an example of code which could be usefull:

```
import threading
import time
def check_time():
    interval = 40 # in seconds
    while 1:
        time.sleep(interval)
        # Call your methods here

t1 = threading.Thread(target=check_time, name='Thread1')
t1.daemon = True
t1.start()
```

The advantage of using a thread as daemon is that you can forget about it in the execution. When you run your program it'll do your background tasks without having the necessity of closing or care about it.